Why won't the Items in my RecyclerView update?
I have this ListAdapter:
ListAdapter<Item, RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder>(object : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Item>() {
        override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: Item, newItem: Item): Boolean {
            return oldItem.id == newItem.id
        }

        override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: Item, newItem: Item): Boolean {
            return oldItem.url == newItem.url
        }
    })

I'm trying to add more Items into the List when a button is clicked. But for some reason the ListAdapter won't notice, if there are new Items. Only when i go to another Fragment and then back it will update my recyclerview.
I've had this issue for a few weeks now and couldn't find any resources about it.
Edit:
This is how I add the Items after your answers
viewModel.addItem()
recyclerViewAdapter.notifyItemInserted(0)

And i observe the itemlist like this:
viewModel.itemList.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { itemList ->
        (binding.recyclerView.adapter as? RecyclerViewAdapter)?.submitList(itemList)
}


did you use adapter.notifyDatasetChanged() after the data is added?

include the code where you add the items

include the code of ListAdapter and where you are trying to update?

By looking at the minimal information provided by you it seems like you are not calling notifyDatasetChanged() on your adapter after adding data to your list. It will be more clear if you post relevant code.

Notifydataset changed is naive and incorrect call to use. As OP is using ListAdapter, all that needs to be done is use submitList(newList). I suspect that he is passing a mutable list to the adapter instead of creating a copy, then he proceeds to alter it which breaks diff calculations.

Its because you are not notifying the adapter that the list has been refreshed or changed.
You should use these after you update the list.notifyItemInserted(position) if you are adding only one value, or notifyItemRangeChanged(position, list.size).
You can use notifyDataSetChanged() for the last resort if the whole list has been updated or nothing mentioned above works for you.

notifyItemRangeChanged(position, list.size) is basically the same as notifyDataSetChanged()

i know but always relying on notifyDataSetChanged() will give us warning, hence should only rely if it is the last option.

a warning is nothing bad, replacing it with equal evil that does not display a warning is pointless
